# Prototype Ajax function help when using Starbox (star rating system) plugin

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm using the [Starbox](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/starbox/) plugin on my website and I want to post the vote value when the visitor votes using AJAX.. I read the plugin documentation and tutorials and it's possible using a function like this:

```
function myOnRate(element, memo) {
  new Ajax.Request('savestar.php', {
    parameters: memo,
    onComplete: function(xhr) {
      // optional callback
    }
  });
}
```

Now I do know PHP but I don't really know javascript or Prototype and I need help with this function.

I know that the 'element' parameter is the ID of the rater and that savestar.php is the external php file that will be called using AJAX.. but beside that I have no idea what to do with this...

I want to send the vote value to savestar.php and then I will get the the value using the POST method and insert it into database. I will also need the 'element' to be sent so I can identify the rater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.... I find the solution myself so here it is:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

            function saveStar(event) {
                new Ajax.Request('savestar.php', {
                parameters: event.memo,
                onComplete: function(xhr) {
                    // optional callback
                }
                });
            }

            // observe just one
            document.observe('dom:loaded', function() { // once the DOM is loaded
                $('elementID').observe('starbox:rated', saveStar);
            });

            new Starbox('elementID', 8, { indicator: 'Rating: #{average} (#{total} votes)', total: 2 });

            </script>
```

If you are reading this and just don't get it just send me a message.